# reading a char array inside a linked list node?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, char, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a Binary search tree using linked list. so my struct for my linked list is:

```
typedef struct node{
    char english[20];
    char span[60];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} BST;
```

How would i access the char array inside the node to modify it? lets say if i have a char `english[]` and i want to copy it into the array inside the node, how would i do that? I used these line but not sure if they are right or not?

```
int counter = 0;
    while(array[counter] != ' ')
    {
        node.english[counter] = array[counter];
        counter++;
    }
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `node`? And have you tried to *build* it? What does the compiler tell you? What does [the rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `node` is of type `BST *`. In such case, you should access it with `->`.

something like:

```
int counter = 0;
while(array[counter] != ' ')
{
    node->english[counter] = array[counter];
    counter++;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it is not protected. You might get a buffer overflow if array is longer than english member. Also, the string you get in english might not be null terminated.

Try using [strlcat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcat) library functions:

```
strlcat(node->english, array, sizeof(node->english);
```